# How to show threshold line in barchart in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts, actionscript, flex4.5

I have to show a bar chart in flex for representing data with threshold value for different kinds of services like data, voice, sms, mms etc. In our array collection I am getting all the related data but I only need to display the threshold values on the chart for data and voice values. I need to show the below given representation of the bar chart in flex.
Please provide any suggestions on how I can get this done. I would be greatful for the same

Comment: `I need to show the below given representation of the bar chart in flex`.. is not there (due to lack of Rep points?) anyway you could describe better what you mean. You say line as though **line chart** but then keep talking about **bar chart**.. if you want lines try this: **[[Example from Flex Manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/LineChart.html)]** scroll to the bottom to see if the end result is what you want

Comment: Hi sir, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByTwPwPY1Dt1MVVsc0tiakNjOTg/view?usp=sharing    This is the exact graph representation I need to show. If you can, then please help me out......Its an urgent requirement from my client. Thank You